# I need a function to be constantly running

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently making a website with changing content and thus changing footer.
I have a function which adapts the footer to the content, it looks like this:

```
(function() {
    var contentHeight = $('#contentwrap').height();
    $('footer').css('top', 510 + contentHeight + 'px');
});
```

It's currently bound to onClick() and I tried setTimeout() but that doesn't work either since I can't predict the time it takes to load the content.
I can't get it to work with setInterval() which seems to be the thing for constantly updating functions.

Please help me

EDIT:

I am aiming for the above function to be running all the time or in short intervals, but don't know how to do it.

Comment: why don't you use css's bottom property or an event?

Comment: That's really a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here

Comment: google fixed footer css. It`s wrong way to fix it using js. And i dont know events on everything loads

Comment: if you don't want to use CSS, you still have the jQuery AJAX `success` event to do what you want

Comment: How can I have the function above be running all the time the page is  is open?

Comment: Rudy, success trigger fill fire when text content loaded. And if there images without width/height specified?

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout; it is slightly more efficient than setInterval (http://reallifejs.com/brainchunks/repeated-events-timeout-or-interval/)

As far as load time, there isn't any way around that. The AJAX request load time will be vary. You could request AJAX at the beginning of the setTimeout and hopefully you have it by the time it completes (you'll need a fallback if it doesn't complete by then). But, in that situation you aren't necessarily getting the "latest" data. My recommendation is just go with a setTimeout, and have the AJAX request occur then. The complete function will update the data on the page...yes...it won't be perfectly timed, but it should be half-way decent.

Answer (score 0):

I think jQuery resize() will helps you:

```
$("#contentwrap").resize(function(){
    var contentHeight = $(this).height();
    //fix footer to bottom if content < window 
    if(contentheight+510+$('footer').height() >$(window).height()) contentHeight = $(window).height()-510;
    $('footer').css('top', 510 + contentHeight + 'px');
});
```